# Is iris really this useless or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: voice-command

Just tried to use iris, the supposed Siri clone for Android:

> **Me to iris:** "Remind me in two hours to get cascade"
>
> **iris:** "What is your real name?"
>
> **Me:** *Why does it need that?* "Josh"
>
> **iris:** "Definition of 'Josh': to jest or tease playfully"
>
> **Me:** "You're useless."
>
> **iris:** "Definition of useless: not fulfilling or not
>   expected to achieve the intended purpose or desired outcome"
>
> **Me:** "Exactly!"

Am I doing it wrong or is iris really just not fulfilling or not expected to achieve the intended purpose or desired outcome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I've seen, Iris isn't supposed to be a competitor for Siri, but rather just a (mostly) joke app that just tries to replicate some of Siri's snarkiness. It's for laughs, not productivity.

If you do want to be productive with voice commands, there are some options. [Vlingo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlingo.client) and [SpeakToIt Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speaktoit.assistant) spring immediately to mind. There are others.

This might be helpful: [Lifehacker: How to get a personal assistant like Siri on your Android phone for free](http://lifehacker.com/5848973/how-to-get-a-personal-assistant-like-siri-on-your-android-phone-for-free)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to ask the right questions.

Here are a few

- calender (Remind me of the meeting coming friday) or (set a reminder this friday)
- Alarm (Set alarm at 540 am)
- Call someone (can you please call Bob)
- text someone (send a text to Bob)
- search nearby (find me a nearby coffee shop)
- play music (play the song rolling in the deep)
- ask movie reviews (should I watch the movie Mission Impossible)
- watch videos (show me a video of cat singing)
- find news (what is the news about SOPA)

These are just a couple of the commands available.